# How do I find all "Famous Questions" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, questions, badges

I frequently look for featured questions, to look for something new to learn I may not be aware of.

I tried looking for "Famous Questions" via the Badges page at https://stackoverflow.com/badges.
That page shows a list of badges, and clicking on a badge shows the users who have that badge, which makes sense for most badges.

But for some badges like "Famous Question", it would be useful if I could see (in this case), the list of Famous Questions.

I searched SO, but no luck so far. Is there such a list somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

This search provides a list of all questions on Stack Overflow for which a [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) badge was awarded.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I made for a previous asker,

> 1. [Questions with highest rated answers](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20parent.ParentId,%20child.Title,%20parent.Score%20FROM%20posts%20AS%20parent,%20posts%20AS%20child%20WHERE%20parent.ParentId%20=%20child.Id%20ORDER%20BY%20Score%20DESC%20LIMIT%20500)
> 2. [Questions with highest rated answers that aren't WIKI's](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20parent.ParentId,%20child.Title,%20parent.Score%20FROM%20posts%20AS%20parent,%20posts%20AS%20child%20WHERE%20parent.ParentId%20=%20child.Id%20AND%20child.IsWiki=0%20ORDER%20BY%20Score%20DESC%20LIMIT%20500)
> 3. [Highest rated Questions](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20Id,%20Title,%20Score%20from%20posts%20WHERE%20PostTypeId=1%20AND%20IsWiki%20=%200%20ORDER%20BY%20Score%20DESC%20LIMIT%20500)

The only downside is you have to append the ID manually to the end of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/`

Comment: Thank you, that helps. But I was really looking to find out if SO had a "proper" page for "Famous Questions"

Comment: There's this, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes`, but most of the questions are more conversation pieces than wonderful questions.

Comment: This probably needs to be updated with links to data explorer queries...