# Find Tricky Question in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

Is there any way to find tricky question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Maybe there is a tag for that etc.?

For example;

[why -3==~2 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471823/why-3-2-in-c)

I love that style questions. They are neither easy nor difficult, but when I learn their solution I feel lucky myself. And I love it.

I look at [Top Votes Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) but they are [Famous Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-do-i-find-all-famous-questions-on-stackoverflow).

Is there any way to find this style questions?

**EDIT**: Is asking here is right or not? I don't know but I want to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trick question" - the behavior you linked to may be unexpected if you aren't familiar with twos-complement arithmetic, but it's not really a trick IMHO.

Comment: @Piskvor You are right. But as i said, these style questions is very useful for me because i'm beginner. NOT trick BUT tricky :)

Comment: Not sure if there is such a tag (and who would tag it like that anyway? The OP? A >20k user?). But if you're interested in puzzle-like questions, perhaps http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ might provide some inspiration?

Comment: A fitting tag would be [not-a-problem].

Comment: Maybe some sort of Amazon type system. "Other people that favourited this question also favourited this..."

Comment: How would __you__ implement such a system? Questions that are "neither easy nor difficult" for you will certainly be too difficult for many other users, and too easy for many more. The "rate each question based on difficulty" approach has been suggested before, but ultimately rejected because it is so subjective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the most famous questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131218/how-to-find-the-most-famous-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for questions that are tagged [brainteaser](/questions/tagged/brainteaser) or [interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainteaser
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [puzzle] tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puzzle