# How to find the most famous questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

How to find questions with

1. most comments
2. most votes
3. most viewed

I have seen following question, but seems like there is no easy way.
[How do I find all "Famous Questions" on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-do-i-find-all-famous-questions-on-stackoverflow)

Is there way to bookmark a page so that the same URL can be used to update data (which will be very seldom) at each hit?

Comment: Just check the list of recently deleted questions :-)

Comment: how to check list of recently deleted questions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all "Famous Questions" on StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-do-i-find-all-famous-questions-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: @HakamFostok: That's asking about a completely different metric, based on score >100.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to query most aspects of the site.

> Stack Exchange Data Explorer allows you to run arbitrary queries on the Stack Exchange public data dumps.

List of queries for:

- [Most Comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=most+comments)
- [Most Votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=most+votes)
- [Most Viewed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=most+views)

Comment: How do you run these for Meta.SE?

Answer (score 8):

You could simply check the list of questions with the most votes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Once you have access to moderator tools on SO, there is a section where you can see questions and answers with "extreme votes".

Additionally, a lot of these very famous questions were eventually deleted. Users with 10k rep can still read them. You can find a list of "Popular deleted questions" here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list

Comment: I think the second link is borken

Answer (score 4):

The [greatest hits page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) is probably the closest built-in mechanism to what you want, except it doesn't take comments into account.  And, of course, closed and deleted questions don't show up, so most of the "famous" SO questions won't show up there.

See also [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Try the Data Explorer query [Posts with lots of comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8491/posts-with-lots-of-comments).

Note that this includes **all post** (questions and answers).

1. That's easy. Just click on the tab `votes` to sort the questions by votes.

Direct link: [Highest Voted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)

1. Two options:

- Try the Data Explorer query [Most Viewed Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67922/most-viewed-questions)
- Search for `views:250000`. Direct link: [Questions containing 'views:250000' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A250000)

The Data Explorer queries have the disadvantage that the data dump it queries isn't might be up to a month old (according to [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77176/131713)).

Comment: 6 months!!! I thought they updated it every month! ??

Comment: @MattFenwick: My mistake. As of 2 days ago, the data dump was still **18** months old ([link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130857/170332)).

Comment: Isn't the link saying that, as of 18 months ago, the data is updated every month or so?

Comment: @MattFenwick: If I had only learned to read...

Comment: [Confirmed](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/68923/my-meta-posts) ... that shows posts from March of this year, so it's no more than 2 months out of date ...

Answer (score 0):

A query to view the top 100 questions by views:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Title, DisplayName AS 'Author', ViewCount AS 'Viewed', Score 
FROM Posts a 
JOIN Users b ON (a.OwnerUserId = b.Id)
ORDER by ViewCount DESC
```

Comment: Try `select top 100 id as [Post Link], owneruserid as [User Link], viewcount, score from posts order by viewcount desc` to leverage magic columns.

Comment: Nice about the links!

Comment: Beyond the [help](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) you might like the [tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) as it is a bit of an hidden gem....