# Which question has the most votes on all sites

Tags: discussion

I am curious that out of all the sites which question has the most votes. I do not know if there is any easy way to do this (and I am to lazy to do it the hard way) so can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: What does "votes" mean? Most Upvotes? Most up and down votes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the most famous questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131218/how-to-find-the-most-famous-questions-on-stack-overflow) - repeat for each site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use The Stack Exchange Data Explorer to feed most of your curiosity.

I've created the following so called networkwide [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1198928). That script basically runs this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1198915) for each site:

```sql
select 
       postid as [Post Link]
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) [upvotes]
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) [downvotes]
     , count(*) [total]
from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where votetypeid in (2,3) -- up , down
and p.posttypeid = 1 -- Q 
group by postid
having count(*) > 200
order by count(*) desc
```

When you run the network wide script today you'll get this list:

[image: sede results]

It confirms the post Rand al'Thor already found is the highest voted question.

Filtering out Stack Overflow gives a somewhat more interesting results:

[image: sede results without stack overflow]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 2):

Since Stack Overflow almost always has the biggest stats of any site on the network, I'm going to go with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq):

[Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809) (score **24094** at time of writing).